# Merge Multiple Row Description With Same ID in One Row on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, aggregate-functions, coalesce

Trust me this is classic but I don't know how to resolve this:

This is my data source

```
    ID   Color  Description 
    -----------------------  
    10   White  MR    
    10   White  DREAM  
    10   White  TURTLENIP
```

My output data expected show like this:

```
    ID   Color   Description 
    ------------------------  
    10   White   MR, DREAM, TURTLENIP
```

I use COALESCE but it seem not work for this report.

P.S this is simple question from my case, my query lot of inner join to merge another table in one report. But I don't know how to merge several row Desc to merge into one row.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want string aggregation. If you are running SQL Server 2017 or higher, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
select id, string_agg(descr, ', ') all_descr
from mytable
group by id
```

Note that `desc` is a language keyword (as in `order by ... desc`), hence not a good choice for a column name. I renamed it to `descr` in the query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, that's real quick, but my question not clear yet, I've been edited my question because I have one field with same content but want to show just one content only (look field "color" for example)

Comment: @agnanzakariya: just add `color` to the `select` clause and to the `group by` clause.